# Django template slow when creating report (many variables, many models, many lists)

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm a newbie trying to use Django to create a report about the participants of a team and  I'm doing something fundamentally wrong and have spent several hours trying to figure out what's going wrong - the report is still hitting the DB about 4000+ times. An abbreviated version of what I'm doing is below.

​

Any help, pointers or other resources would be **much** appreciated!

​

For the Team model:

```
class Team(BenchmarkData):
    year = models.ForeignKey(Period, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    sponsor = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    goal = models.ForeignKey(Goal, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
        ...other non-relational properties...

    def _participation_queryset(self):
        from .participation import Participation
        pp = Participation.objects.filter(team=self.id)
                return pp

    @cached_property
    def average_points(self):
        list_participation = [participation.calculated_yearly_points_per_hour for participation in self._participation_queryset()] 
        try: return mean(list_participation)

    @cached_property
    ...
```

For the Participation model:

```
class Participation(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    year = models.ForeignKey(Period, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    start_date = models.DateField('Began', null=True)
    end_date = models.DateField('Left', blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField('Active?', null=True)

    yearly_points = models.FloatField(default=0, null=True)
    yearly_hours_of_play = models.FloatField(default=0)
        ...other non-relational properties...

    @cached_property
    def calculated_yearly_points_per_hour(self):
        try: return self.yearly_points / self.yearly_hours_of_play
        except ZeroDivisionError: return 0

        ...other cached properties...
```

For my View, I used:

```
class PlanReport(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'pension/report/index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        self.team = get_object_or_404(Plan, id=self.kwargs['team_id'])
        self.sponsor = get_object_or_404(Company, id=self.kwargs['sponsor_id'])
        self.report = get_object_or_404(Report, id=self.kwargs['plan_id'])

        pp = Participation.objects.filter(plan_id=self.plan)
        s = pickle.dumps(pp.query)
        s2 = pickle.loads(s)
        participation_list = s2.model.objects.all()

        # Add in other context information
        context['team'] = self.team
        context['sponsor'] = self.sponsor
        context['report'] = self.report
        context['participation_list'] = participation_list

        return context
```

The report template structure is:

```
index.html
 - section1.html
 - section2-table-of-group-participants-with-stats-on-each-participant.html
...
```

And the templates for the table shows:

```
...other html...
    {% for participation in participation_list %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ participation.person }}</td>
            <td>{{ participation.team }}</td>
            <td>{{ participation.year }}</td>
            <td>{{ participation.start_date }}</td>
            <td>{{ participation.end_date }}</td>
            <td>{{ participation.active }}</td>
            <td>{{ participation.yearly_points }}</td>
            <td>{{ participation.yearly_hours_of_play }}</td>
            <td>{{ participation.calculated_yearly_points_per_hour }}</td>
                ...other calculated attributes...
    </tr>
    {% empty %}
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <p>No data imported into the list</p>
    {% endfor %}
```

​

Thanks for the replies so far!

@Daniel Roseman:

Thanks a bunch.

I reverted all the @cached_properies to @property as you mentioned (I had a suspicion they were slowing things down!)

I removed all the pickle stuff — it was something I heard from someone so was trying to do, but didn't quite understand how it related very well — so I guess it doesn't really relate to caching much — at least in my situation.

I've also changed the following:

In the team model:

```
def _participation_queryset(self):
    from .participation import Participation
    return self.participation_set.all()
```

In the create_report view:

```
    participation_list = self.team.participation_set.all().select_related('team')

    ...

    context['participation_list'] = participation_list
```

Comment: If I am understanding this correctly your site is going too slow because your database is being pinged too many times. I think this would be a perfect time to use Redis for caching which is waaay faster than a traditional database.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of major inefficiencies in your code.

The first is that you have defined your own way of getting the participants for a team, with your `_participation_queryset` method. That is not only unnecessary, it *breaks* Django's built-in caching; it will be evaluated each time it is called. Remove it and refer to `self.participation_set.all()`.

The other, and probably even more important, one is that you don't do anything to preload any of the related data for any of your models. So each call to `{{ participation.team }}` causes a database hit, even though you actually already have the team. You should use `select_related` when you fetch the Participation queryset in your view (which you should do via the same call to `participation_set`).

(And I can't understand what you are doing with that pickle dump/load thing there. Why on earth are you doing that? Also note, there's no reason to be assigning the values as instance attributes.)

So your view looks like this:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    team = get_object_or_404(Plan, id=self.kwargs['team_id'])
    sponsor = get_object_or_404(Company, id=self.kwargs['sponsor_id'])
    report = get_object_or_404(Report, id=self.kwargs['plan_id'])

    participation_list = team.participation_set.all().select_related('team')
    ...
```

Finally, I don't think your cached_properties are doing what you think they are, and are probably making things even more inefficient. Something like `calculated_yearly_points_per_hour` is a simple division of two integers and is trivial to calculate; there is no need at all to cache it. Remove most if not all of those decorators.

Comment: Thanks Daniel! I've updated the post with the changes I made … is that correct? Also, a quick subquestion: so you were talking about my template variables, like `{{ participation.team }}` - do I have to change the way I'm accessing those from the template? Currently: `{% for participation in participation_list %}` and `{{ participation.team }}` is that still okay, or am I still doing something wrong there?

Comment: No those stay the same.